# How I can round UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer, layoutsubviews

In my UICollectionViewCell class I wrote this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius  = CGRectGetHeight(self.myImageView.frame) / 2;
    self.myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

But this does not work correctly in all cases, it appears like this:

[image]

Comment: Works for me alright. Can't see anything wrong with your code. Try accessing width directly instead of using a getter for height. `self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;`http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

Comment: Also You are setting corner radius in `viewDidLayOutSubviews`. It is called multiple times for each subview being added. Dont put it there

Comment: For circle your height and width must be equal. And cornerRadius should be half of height or width. Add self. myImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: Great catch Muhammad.

Comment: You are right, Good point  Muhammad, but still it does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced a similar problem [trying to get a collectionView inside a TableView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364092/2893809).

If you are changing your cell's model you should tell the cell to recalculate its layout so the cell changes its size and calls `layoutIfNeeded`.

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
         UICollectionViewCell*cell = ...
         // Do your stuff here to configure the cell
         // Tell the cell to redraw its contentView        
         [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }
```